# Displaying Image as a result of operations with Flask and AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, flask

I'm currently working on a project, in which an explainable AI library for CNN image recognition (https://github.com/albermax/innvestigate) is meant to be implemented in a web-service. Now, I found a good looking template, which involved general image recognition back- & frontend, based on Flask (https://github.com/OkanKY/keras-flask-webapp).

I managed to implement the library, but do not manage to display the resulting plot-image on the web-service. This is what I tried:

Python/Flask Code:

```
@app.route('/predictResNet50', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def predictResNet50():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file_path = get_file_path_and_save(request)

        ...

        plt.savefig(file_path[:-4] + explainer + "Plot.jpg")
        fullPlotFilename = file_path[:-4] + explainer + "Plot.jpg"
       
        ...

        return fullPlotFilename
```

By that, the plot image is perfectly stored in the static/images library. The corresponding JavaScript code, which invokes the API, looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/predictResNet50',
            data: form_data,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            async: true,
            success: function (data) {
                // Get and display the result
                $('.loaderResNet50').hide();
              //  $('#resultResNet50').fadeIn(600);
              //  $('#resultResNet50').text(' Result:  ' + data1);
                $('#plotResNet50').show();
                $('#plotResNet50').html('<img src="' + data + '">');
                console.log('ResNet50 Success!');
            },
        });
```

Before the modifications, the result of the prediction was displayed (out-commented part). Now, the plot image is supposed to be displayed. Ideally, the result plus the prediction would be the goal, but for now, the plot would be sufficient. But this does not work for some reason. The correct value is returned to the API call in JS, but **only the image adress, not the actual image** is presented.

HTML Script:

```
<div id="plotResNet50">
</div>
```

Could somebody tell me, what I'm missing? Since I'm not too experienced with JQuery, help would be greatly appreciated!!

Link to the current GitLab Repo can be provided, if the stated information is not sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `html()` is not the appropriate function to be used if  you intend to add an element to HTML using JQuery.

Instead use:

`$('#plotResNet50').prepend('<img src="' + data + '">')`